Consumption Azure function exceed quotas
I have an Azure function with a consumption plan.
Plan


 Function App 


The function has always work well but a few days ago (Friday 20) I received an error that says "The function app has reached daily usage quota and has been stopped".
I do not understand which quota I've reached (also because with a consumption plan I do not expect to have quotas).I checked everywhere: app insight, azure monitor, metrics etc. and I do not find anything useful. 
Any suggestions on what the problem might be or where to look for more informations?

Refer this article.

I've run into a similar issue with similar timing as well. We're still trying to figure out what is going on. Our usage for the functions in question are relatively small, so usage quota limits don't really make sense. We've ended up deploying the functions to a windows environment, as Linux deployments seem to be buggy for some reason.

The function app with consumption plan pricing depends on the amount of memory consumed and is billed based on resource consumption and executions per-second, Refer the article.

The function app has reached daily usage quota and has been stopped


This error leads to the execution of your app getting blocked until the next day 0:00AM UTC.

As mentioned in the article[Step 7 - Configure a Daily Use Quota]:

The Azure Functions consumption plan offers scalability to manage the sudden load spikes. But this can cause increase in costs if there is a denial of service (DoS) attack or coding errors leads to extensive scaling.

In such cases, the daily quota allows you to set a limit in terms of "Gigabyte seconds" (GB-s).

By default, the daily usage quota is set to unlimited(zero) to prevent any unexpected cost issues, it is better to define the limit. Once the function app reaches the limit, it goes to Disabled state till next day.


Increase the daily quota in the function app=>function runtime settings and restart the function app.
The status of function app should be Running as below:

